# JQuery slideUp and slideDown not working well in Chrome

Tags: jquery

It overshoots the mark then goes back up again in Chrome but not Firefox...

Scroll over the images here http://dev.nkt-kmc-manjushri.org/

This is the code i'm using.

```
// Set height on excerpt for smooth animation
jQuery(".excerpt").each (function() {
    jQuery(this).css("height", jQuery(this).height());
});

// Hide excerpts by default
jQuery('.excerpt').hide();

// Fade in 
jQuery(".slide").hoverIntent({
    over: slidein,
    timeout: 100,
    out: slideout
}); 

function slidein(){ 
    // jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.excerpt').animate({"height":500},400);
    jQuery('.slide').not(this).animate({opacity:0.3},400);
    jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.excerpt').slideDown(500);    
} 
function slideout(){ 
    // jQuery(this).find('.excerpt').animate({"height":0},400);
    jQuery('.slide').removeClass('active').animate({opacity:1},400);
    jQuery(this).find('.excerpt').slideUp(1500);    
}
```

Comment: Another pb occurs if the element you apply this on has a min-height !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the .height() method causing the problem? Perhaps try setting a fixed height just with css (not javascript)?

```
height: 18em;
```

The problem I am seeing is that if I move my mouse over several of the items before each animation occurs it has odd behaviour. I see the text replaced by an image if I move fast enough.

Perhaps consider doing this:

```
jQuery('.slide').not(this).stop().animate({opacity:0.3},400);
```

jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.excerpt').stop().slideDown(500);

and this:

```
jQuery('.slide').stop().removeClass('active').animate({opacity:1},400);
```

jQuery(this).addClass('active').find('.excerpt').stop().slideDown(500);

stop() cancels the current animation.

You could also use the callback that .animate, .slideUp and .slideDown provide. From the docs:

```
.animate( properties, [ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )
```

and

```
.slideUp( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
```

And then bind and unbind to some custom events to do the animations for you, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Sadly the first two solutions didn't work. I'll try the last if I can figure it out. Thanks.